# Java wierd calculations

Tags: java, rotation

I had a headache for some hours trying to figure out what was wrong in my rotation algorithm and finally I found out that there was a problem  in java interpretation of such calculations:

```
float playerCenterX = 248.0f;
float playerCenterY = 248.0f;
playerCenterX = (float)((playerCenterX - (float)512) * Math.cos(angle) - (playerCenterY - (float)300) * Math.sin(angle) + (float)512);
playerCenterY = (float)((playerCenterX - (float)512) * Math.sin(angle) + (playerCenterY - (float)300) * Math.cos(angle) + (float)300);
```

The code above was giving really unexpected results, instead of rotating the point around (512, 300) about specified angle it was giving me coordinates that form an infinity symbol ( with angle from 0 to 2PI).

And now such a minor, seemingly unimportant and irrelevant change fixes the code above:

```
float playerCenterX = 248.0f;
float playerCenterY = 248.0f;
float playerCenterX2 = (float)((playerCenterX - (float)512) * Math.cos(angle) - (playerCenterY - (float)300) * Math.sin(angle) + (float)512);
float playerCenterY2 = (float)((playerCenterX - (float)512) * Math.sin(angle) + (playerCenterY - (float)300) * Math.cos(angle) + (float)300);
```

So subscribing a result of the calculation to a new variable, not used in the right side of equation solves the problem. Now... could someone explain me what's happening here?

Answer (score 4):

When playerCenterY calculated it uses modified playerCenterX. And in second version you use pristine values.

Comment: oh crap... it's so painful now to discover the truth... thanks for pointing this out for me

Comment: It's hard, when you work on problem for long, to find a bug in place where you're not expecting it :) You're welcome.

Comment: @Savail, Don't worry. we have all been there.

Answer (score 1):

Its because earlier you were using the modified value of your same variable `playerCenterX`.

```
playerCenterX = (float)((playerCenterX - (float)512) * Math.cos(angle) - (playerCenterY - (float)300) * Math.sin(angle) + (float)512);
playerCenterY = (float)((playerCenterX - (float)512) * Math.sin(angle) + (playerCenterY - (float)300) * Math.cos(angle) + (float)300);
```

So in the above code lets say first time the value is set to `248.0f` then it is modified and `playerCenterY` was getting the updated value of `playerCenterX` which you were expecting to be `248.0f`

And in the second part you are assigning the value to a seperate variable and so the value of `playerCenterX`  is not changed and it remains the same as `248.0f`.